# Include owl Carousel and funcybox in my MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I include owl Carousel and funcybox in my MVC project?

I download owl Carousel from Nuget and in my common.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var owl = $(".carousel");
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 2,
        autoHeight: true
    });
});
```

In my BundleConfig I have:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/owl.carousel.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"));
```

And in my html:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <div class="carousel">
                            <div class="slide_item"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/iv6qWgb.jpg"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide_item"><img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/6900000/Andy-Murray-wallpapers-3-tennis-6904485-1024-768.jpg"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

But Carousel did not work. Why?

Comment: Where is your document.Ready code? It needs to be under Script.Render and your Divs.

Comment: <script src="/Scripts/common.js"></script>       My document.Ready code in file common.js

Comment: andrey1567 - no the question was is that line that you just commented before @Scripts.Render in your cshtml file?  it should be after

Comment: @Scripts.Render this element under footer for my page

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add CSS files to bundle?
For example:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/OwlCarousel/owl.carousel.css",
    "~/Content/OwlCarousel/owl.theme.css",
    "~/Content/OwlCarousel/owl.transitions.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/site.css"));
```